# Передача структуры через сокет TCP/IP

Tags: c, сокет, структуры, передача-данных

Пытаюсь передать файл через структуру и через сокет - задание такое, поэтому другие варианты использовать не могу, необходимо соблюдение протокола.

Выравнивание (вроде) есть, упаковка тоже..

Используя нулевой массив, хочу записать туда имя файла, например.

Примеров обращения к нулевому массиву, выделению ему памяти и использованию я нашёл только один и частично использовал, но всё равно не работает, не понимаю, как корректно обращаться к нулевому массиву..

Проблема - ошибка

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     albert->c[strlen(argv[2])] = argv[2];
```

Не могли бы вы мне, пожалуйста, помочь?

СЕРВЕР:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                     
#include <string.h>                                                                                     
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                      
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                  
#include <sys/socket.h>                                                                                 
#include <netinet/in.h>    
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#pragma pack(1)   
struct packet {
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b;
  char c[0];
 // char* d;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
#pragma pack(0)

int main(){

int sd, file_write_len;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
char ch;

sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(6666);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.79");

int rc;
rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, NULL, 1);
rc = bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
                                                                                                                            
if (rc){perror("bind() call failed"); exit(1); }
  
  if (listen(sd, SOMAXCONN) == -1)
  {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
  }

int epfd = epoll_create1(0);
if(0 > epfd){perror("epoll_create1"); exit(1);} 

struct epoll_event server_event;
  server_event.events = EPOLLIN;
  server_event.data.fd = sd;
  if (epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sd, &server_event) == -1)
  {
    perror("epoll_ctl");
    exit(1);
  }

static struct epoll_event ev, events[1024];

ev.events = EPOLLIN;
ev.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
  if (epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &ev) == -1)
  {
    perror("epoll_ctl");
    exit(1);
  }
ev.data.fd = sd;

int myfile;

int events_cout = 1;
for(;;){

int nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 1024, -1);
if (nfds == -1)
    {
      perror("epoll_wait");
      exit(1);
    }
else{
  printf("number of connections is %d\n", nfds);
}

for(int i = 0; i < nfds; i++)
    {
      if (events[i].data.fd == sd)
      {
        struct  sockaddr_in client_address;                                                                                                       
        int client_address_len;                                                                                                        
        client_address_len = sizeof(client_address);                                                                                                     
        int cd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_len);                                                                                                                                                                           
        printf("ADRESS is %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr)); 

        if (events_cout == 1023)
        {
        printf("Event array is full");
        close(cd);
        continue;
        }
        ++events_cout;
        

        struct packet albert;
        recv(cd, &albert, sizeof(albert), 0);

            uint8_t *recv_data = (uint8_t *)&albert;
            size_t recv_len = sizeof(albert);

            printf("1. %d\n", albert.a);
            printf("2. %d\n", albert.b);
            printf("3. %s\n", albert.c);
      //  myfile = fopen(albert.c, "wb+");
      //  write(myfile, albert.d, albert.b);
      //  fclose(myfile);
      } 
}
}

close(sd);
return  0;
}
```

КЛИЕНТ:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                     
#include <string.h>                                                                                     
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                      
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                  
#include <sys/socket.h>                                                                                 
#include <netinet/in.h>    
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#pragma pack(1)  
struct data {
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b;
  char c[0]; 
 // char* d;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
#pragma pack(0)

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

printf("%s", argv[2]);

int sd, cd;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
char ch;

sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (sd == -1) { printf("socket creation failed...\n"); exit(0); } 
else {printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); }
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr)); 

addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((const char*) argv[1]); 
addr.sin_port = htons(6666); 


if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) { 
    printf("connection with the server failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else {
    printf("connected to the server..\n"); }

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[2], "rb");

    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    long FSIZE = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);


    struct data *albert =
        malloc(sizeof(struct data) +
                  sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[2]));
#pragma pack(0)
    albert->a = strlen(argv[2]);
    albert->b = FSIZE;
    albert->c[strlen(argv[2])] = argv[2];
 // albert.d = malloc(sizeof(char) * FSIZE);
    
    send(sd, &albert, sizeof(albert), 0);
fclose(f);
close(sd);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что Вы хотели сделать строкой `albert->c[strlen(argv[2])] = argv[2];` ? по адресу за пределами массива записываете адрес (4 или 8 байт), который точно не будет иметь смысла в другом процессе. Странненько.

По хорошему, нужно копировать побайтно.

```
memcpy(albert->c, argv[2], albert->a);
```

теперь пойдем в сервер.

```
struct packet albert;
recv(cd, &albert, sizeof(albert), 0); // ок, прочитали начало структуры

uint8_t *recv_data = (uint8_t *)&albert; // делаем что то странное
size_t recv_len = sizeof(albert); // и ещё раз что то странное
```

давайте делать это правильно

```
int len;
recv(cd, &len, sizeof(len)); // прочитали первые 4 байта структуры, что бы узнать реальный размер.

struct data *albert = malloc(len); // создадим нужно размера
albert->a = len; // мы это уже прочитали...
recv(cd, albert+sizeof(len), len-sizeof(len)); // дочитали хвост.
```

если я нигде не ошибся, то все должно работать. Хотя там ещё данные читаются из файла, и это нужно будет аккуратно обработать.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, выглядит логично, исправил таким образом. Но правильно ли считывать первые 4 байта структуры, полагая, что это именно байты внутри структуры и именно сейчас нам прилетит uint32_t ? Пока я искал информацию по поводу отправки структур, на форумах и т.д отвечали, что самое главное - инициализировать и принять структуру одним recv (и аналогичным send). Так же, как и отправили.
Я попробовал вашим способом, затем просто принять структуру целиком или инициализировать её с указателем, как я делаю это в клиенте. Принимая вашим способом или целиком - в структуре мусор из чисел.

Comment: До того как я засунул туда char[0] и выделил ему память, в структуре были только int и это работало корректно..

Comment: порядок переменных в структуре регламентируется стандартом. У Вас по факту структура может иметь разный размер, так что просто принять ее нельзя, нужно знать ее размер. Очень часто размер передают отдельно.

Comment: но, в любом случае, крайне желательно проверять, сколько байт было отправлено и получено (send и recv это возвращают). Очень часто, recv может немного не прочитать (особенно, если стоит безумный фаервол/антивирус. у меня так было - всегда первым читался только один байт, а следующей попыткой чтения читалось все остальное. удаляешь фаервол (одной вредной фирмы) и все стает работать как нужно)

Comment: Проверил - send и recv(в два захода) оба по 8 байт! Да и на моём полупустом линухе для начинающих нет фаервола :) Наверное, моя гениальная (не очень) упаковка структуры не сработала и всё поломалось..

Comment: а сколько у Вас размер самой структуры albert? 8 байт. И поэтому send(sd, &albert, sizeof(albert), 0); отправит только 8 байт. sizeof вычисляется на этапе компиляции и ничего не знает о том, что программист учудил с структурой. Но Вы же malloc делали и реальный размер знаете. Возьмите его там в отдельную   переменную и используйте в send, Правда я сейчас понял, что мой способ чтения будет работать плохо, его нужно немного доделать - рассчитать корректный размер для структуры и кол-во байт для чтения. Но думаю, сможете управиться

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно скопируйте строку

```
memmove(albert->c, argv[2], albert->a);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это сработало, но, к сожалению, мой Альберт на сервере теперь (после выделения ему памяти новым образом + вставки массива) принимается как куча бессмысленных чисел и мусора - буду смотреть дальше!